# Cannot find module '/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node'

Tags: node.js

I'm getting the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/java/build/Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node'
Require stack:
- /Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js
- /Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/java/index.js
- /Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/xslt4node/lib/xslt4node.js
- /Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/xslt4node/index.js
- /Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/transform.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kavishka/Documents/odata-openapi/tools/node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
```

I'm trying out https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi/tree/master/tools

and when I run odata-openapi -dp ../examples/Northwind.xml I get the following error

Comment: Is `node-gyp` configured properly? Usually any binding issue can be traced down to improper `node-gyp` configuration.

Comment: When trying to configure node-gyp i'm getting this error,

gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/kavishka) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure"
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: did you do a npm install -g inside the tools directory? I tried out the above I seems to work ok for me.

Comment: @Kavishka `node-gyp` is definitely failing on some dependency then. Recheck python for `npm config`. Native bindings can be a mess and this is definitely not an issue with odata but a config issue.

Comment: There was an error with node-gyp. No matter how many times is re-installed it, it was causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue I did the following,
- Uninstalled node
- Used yarn to install node

This solved all node related issues.